# how do I clear out log files and such

Tags: hard-drive, logging

I have 9.5 GB of log files and would like to clear them from my system and keep that much stuff from being created, how do I do this?

Here is the output from `sudo du -sh /var/* ~/.xsession-errors`:

```
13M /var/backups
204M    /var/cache
112M    /var/crash
4.0K    /var/games
503M    /var/lib
4.0K    /var/local
0       /var/lock
9.5G    /var/log
85M     /var/mail
4.0K    /var/metrics
24K     /var/opt
0       /var/run
1.7M    /var/spool
391M    /var/tmp
11G     /var/tvmobili
20K     /var/www
224K    /home/school/.xsession-errors
```

Comment: What is making your logs grow to that size? That seems a bit excessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two programs work great in cleaning: Ubunutu Tweak and Bleachbit. The first is user-friendly and therefore less dangerous and therefore less powerful. The second can break your system but if you know what you're doing can be really useful.

Good luck

Comment: I happen to use bleachbit myself for general stuff, but I also have a script do delete logs... This previous post is useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/171678/ubuntu-can-i-delete-var-log-files-due-to-low-root-space