# Where are ALL ubuntu logs/terminal history stored

Tags: bash, security, history, logs, secure-erase

In what folders are the logs and key histories stored so that I may make a script to purge them.  Is there a specific folder for the hibernation partition or a file by which it keeps the RAM data on hibernate?  Is someone wanted to get rid of all command history/program load history/program execution history, where would they go?

Answer (score 15):

There are a lot of places where things get logged, and it will be very diffucult to be exhaustive, depending on what applications you use. That said, here are the main places I can think of:

- most system logs go into `/var/log`
- firefox stores your history, cookies, etc... in `~/.mozilla/firefox`
  This can be purged from Firefox (shift+ctrl+suppr)
- zeitgeist is an history daemon, that populates the dash recent history. It can be purged from the privacy settings
- terminal command history is saved on a per-user basis in `~/.bash_history` Deleting this file will remove this history.
- gnome applications (gedit, nautilus, etc...) store recently used files in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` This file can be deleted if needed.

These are the main places I can think of, but any application can log things in various places... so it really depends on what logs you want to remove.

As mentionned by MrVaykadji, [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) is a GPL software that automates such cleansing task, and let you delete "log files" for a wide variety of known softwares. You can also easily add new cleaners with simple xml files. Might be what you are (ware) looking for!

Comment: I don't know if it is recommended, but I think `BleachBit` could be an "easy" solution for logs on mainstream programs.

Comment: @MrVaykadji this is certainly an interesting to know project! Source code is available, and so called cleaners xml files give us a lot of information on various softwares. I'll update my answer to include this! Thanks a lot.

Comment: It also is a powerful tool, enough powerful to delete the wrong files and compromise your system. But maybe it is well coded and secure, I don't know.

Comment: It seems that BleachBit will dry run and output a list of to-be-deleted files, before actualy deleting... But surely it must be used with caution.

Answer (score 12):

It is located in: `~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 5):

Your bash history file is in your home directory:    `/home/your-user-name/.bash_history`

Zeitgeist user history is stored in  `~/.local/share/zeitgeist`.

To reset the Zeitgeist history, open a terminal and copy/paste the following commands:

```
rm ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite
```

Or navigate to that directory in Nautilus or your file manager and  manually delete the sqlite database "activity.sqlite". It will be created again by Zeitgeist minus your previous user history.

I do not feel comfortable telling  users to use some    commands unless they understand the command completely  and  are  careful to double check that the command is written correctly,  especially any command  beginning with **rm**  since   a user could easily  do irreparable damage to their system if the command was incorrectly formatted, but to better answer the OP's question as suggested in comments, the  system logs are stored in 
`var/log`
 But I have heard of people  causing  problems by deleting  subdirectories inside the log directory
as is mentioned here [[Can I delete /var/log files due to low root space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171678/can-i-delete-var-log-files-due-to-low-root-space)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171678/can-i-delete-var-log-files-due-to-low-root-space)

But keep in mind that if you need to troubleshoot some  system problem the logs will be very useful.

You can delete the contents of the journal folder by opening  a terminal and copy and paste the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/log/journal/*
```

To see how much space it is using on your computer you can open a terminal and issue the query:

`journalctl --disk-usage`

My system is currently is using  3.9GB.

Comment: That only refers to the terminal history. You should edit your answer with a way to remove Ubuntu Logs, as asked (hint: Zeitgeist is also one of the logs to clean)

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry for the incomplete answer and I did not even mention var/logs,  I forgot  about zeitgeist because   for the past several years  I always disable zeitgeist and use gnome flashback / metacity even on this new 18.04 (Bionic) computer and in fact  it was one of the first things I did after  a clean install when  Trusty reached EOL so I had forgotten about Zeitgeist. I see this answer was already edited for clarity by MrVaykadji. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It has to be taken under consideration that other than the logs mentioned above, many (if not most) applications keep their own individual logs in different locations.  So as mentioned by alci, the answer really depends on what you want to sanitize.

Also it would be wise that, if the need does really exist you may want to try out your script writing skills to automate based on actual, specific needs of log sanitizing.