# Where can I find logs of all media files played/accessed by a user?

Tags: video, log, search

I have a bit of a conundrum.

Yesterday I was organizing some home video archives, and I accidentally moved a file into the wrong folder of about 3000 other clips, before copying said folder onto a new disk and wiping the original.

They're records of battery testing, so thumbnails all visually very similar - which means finding this clip again will mean going through each clip, one at a time. Sadly they all have the same creation/modification timestamps now too, so can't even get a hint there.

The only hope is - I watched the file before moving it yesterday. So I'm hoping that SOMEWHERE on that ubuntu machine, there's a log file that says I accessed [filename].mp4, which I can then search for in the new archive.

So - for the forensics experts out there - are there any logs in the system that track what media files are played/opened. I was using the MPV deb at the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are ALL ubuntu logs/terminal history stored](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297053/where-are-all-ubuntu-logs-terminal-history-stored)

Comment: Well, I've previously turned off the " ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel " history,  and I dont  user terminal at all. Firefox wasn't involved in this either so that just leaves /var/log...there seem to be a lot of files in there and most aren't readable for some reason. Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you added a [script](https://github.com/hacel/recent) for it yourself.